About Peano axioms and equivalence relation closure.
Consider a enough good foundation of (a enought working) elementary set theory, with Peano axiom's (and without general intersection of subsets).
I try to translate the topic inside a elementar spatial boolean topos...without reference to completennes of $Set$ given by Zermelo Fraenkel foundation or similar.
If we have a set $N$ with a injective map $s: N\to N$ such that its image leave just one element $0\in N$,  and define $R:=\{(n, s(n)| n\in N\}\subset N\times N$  then $\hat{R}$ (the equivalnce relation generated by inductive construction using Peano)  is equal to $N\times N$, and we have that $N \cong \mathbb{N}$ (natural numbers set).
Now,  if we sostituite Peano with the follow:
(EqRel) for each relation on a set $R\subset A\times A$, exists a minimal equivalence relation $\hat{R}$ containing $R$
Then form (EqRel) I'll call a Peano scheme a set $N$ with a injective map $s: N\to N$ with just one point $0$ out its image and such that if $R\subset N\times N$ is the image of $1_N\times s$  then $\hat{R}=N\times N$.
Can I deduce from this axiom (EqRel) a model of Peano axiom's ? (with some enough right precondictions).
EDIT(1)
I mean that are a Boolean operations (finite) between sets and subsets, the product and the (finite) sum of subsets are permitted, quotient by equivalence realtions,  usual operation with functions, and first order logic as language (for which the closure $\hat{R}$ of a relation $R$ cannot be expressed as the intersection of all equivalence relations containing $R$).
CONCRETELY: If we have an elementary set theory (with the aforementioned operations), and if I have the above $(EqRel)$ as axiom instead Peano...
and have (what I called)  a Peano-scheme: a set $N$ with an injective function $s: I\to I$ with only one element $o\in N$ do not belong to the image of $s$, such that $\hat{R}=N\times N$ where $R:=\{(n, s(s)| n\in N\}$, then I wonder:
given $J\subset N$ with $o\in J$ and $s^{-1}(J)\subset J$ (i.e. $s: J\to J$),   is it true that $J=N$ ? (to be proved without the principle of natural induction).
The basic idea is that the construction of the closure $\hat{R}$ of a relation $R$, (using first order logic) uses the principle of induction, the idea is if vice versa (reciprocally) using this construction as an axiom we can deduce Peano's axioms.
P.S. You will have understood that English is not my native language, if I seem rude it is inadvertent and I apologize.

I'm not sure what $1_N \times s$ means in this context. Do you mean that $R$ is the graph of the function $s$, $R = {(n,s(n)) \mid n \in N}$?

Lee Mosher, thank, just edited.

I don't think your idea works, nonetheless I think that with a slight correction it can be made to work.
I'm going to avoid your $1_N \times s$ notation and instead use $R = \{(n,s(n)) \mid n \in N\}$ as suggested in my comment.
First, we can prove with a minimal amount of set theory that your highlighted statement is simply true: for each relation on a set $R \subset A \times A$ there does exist a minimal equivalence relation $\hat R$ on the set $A$ containing $R$. Namely, let $\textbf R$ be the set of all equivalence relations on the set $A$ containing $R$, and then define $\hat R = \bigcap \textbf R$. Another proof is to let $\hat R$ be the reflexive, symmetric, transitive closure of $R$.
But also, your highlighted statement does not prove Peano's Axioms. What matters is the existence of an appropriate function $s$. So you could correct your statement to say this: Peano's Axioms are equivalent to the existence of a Peano scheme $s : S \to N$ such that $\hat R = N \times N$.

One last issue: in set theory with a good enough foundation, the existence of a Peano scheme such that $\hat R = N \times N$ can be proved. I'm not sure at what "elementary" level this could be accomplished; the proof I know requires the axiom of infinity which is one of the axioms of ZFC set theory.

Suppose cannot do general intersections, I ask how (and if) can obtain the Peano axioms, from the axiom that states the existence of the minimal equivalence relation $\hat{R}$ containing a relation $R$.

I think that makes the question harder. My answer addresses your question as stated before the edits, but not this harder question. I'm not sure the harder question has a positive answer. For instance, what if $R$ is the dictionary order on the set $A = ({0} \times \mathbb N) \cup ({1} \times \mathbb Z)$?

This also highlights an unfortunate vagueness of your original question: Exactly what kind of "elementary set theory" are you allowing?
